# Validating a column with another sheet's particular column values in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[image]

[image]

I have two excel sheets **Students** and **StudentCourse** in my workbook. In the first Sheet i.e. students I need to validate Student ID for unique and length of the Student ID is between 1 and 20 characters. I used the custom Data validation and my rule is

> =AND(LEN(A2)<=20, LEN(A2) > 0, COUNTIF($A$2:$A$65536, A2) =1)

which is working as expected.

Now in the second sheet i.e. StudentCourse, I need to validate to insert only those Student IDs which are present in the Students sheet's Student ID column and Student IDs can be repeated. I put the custom validation as

> =AND(LEN(A2) <= 20, LEN(A2) > 0, COUNTIF(Students!A2:A65536, A2) > 0)

but I am unable to validate as expected.

Could you please help me to get the expected validation?

Comment: Could it be because you didn't use absolute referencing in your `COUNTIF()`?

Comment: And both `LEN()`s are redundant :)

Comment: Your second formula is referencing a sheet called `Titles`. Is that intended?

Comment: @MoacirI I corrected the reference sheet Titles = Students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reference in formula to Students! worksheet is set to relative. please use absolute reference as stated below. Please confirm if this resolves your issue.

> =AND(LEN(A2) <= 20, LEN(A2) > 0, COUNTIF(Students!$A$2:$A$65536, A2) > 0)

Comment: You could just use `Students!$A:$A` although doubt the whole column is necessary.